# Using .html page views instead of .php? CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, view

In CodeIgniter I have view files that end in .html and others that end in .php. With the .html files it seems like I can still insert PHP code and it works fine. Really I notice no difference between the two types. What's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use html files like on code below only difference really is that on the controller you need to include .html

```
$this->load->view('example.html');

// Passing Data

$data['title'] = 'Something';

$this->load->view('example.html', $data);
```

Where php

```
$this->load->view('example');

// Passing Data

$data['title'] = 'Something';

$this->load->view('example', $data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Good point about needing to include the file extension for .html when calling the view!